# Register users only through DApp sign-up

Tags: solidity, signature, authentication

I am making a DApp where users need to be registered in the Solidity smart contract to perform some actions, for example:

```
function publish (string memory _itemURI) userOnly public {
    // Publish item
}
```

Where the userOnly modifier is as follows

```
modifier userOnly {
    require(users[msg.sender] == true, "User only");
    _;
}
```

Registration is done with this function:

```
function register(address newUser) public {
    users[newUser] = true;
    emit Register(newUser);
}
```

The problem is: anyone could call the register function to register there own address, and then be  able to call the userOnly functions. Is there a way the register function could only be called only at the end of our DApp sign-up process, like only after the user signs our terms of service with Metamask?

Answer (score 0):

your dapp needs to control a wallet that registers users(hard). registration needs a "dappOnly" modifier or you need to add a comment on the source code that discloses the TOS(easier).

Comment: Alright, but if I wanted the dApp's address to call the register function, then I'd have to store the private key somewhere. Even if it's in the env vars of Fleek, it's still a security risk. So is there a way that the user calls the register function, but can only do so from the dApp?

Comment: No not really, that's why I say it's safest to just put your TOS into the comments of your code. It shouldn't contribute to the contact's bytecode length at all. Legal contract inside a smart contract!